# ksh: grep command for multiple string. If all the strings found then only return the result

Tags: unix, grep, ksh

is there any way to grep 2 strings in ksh and only return true if both the string found?

we can use the egrep command if any of the string is found. but for matching all the string and return true only all the string present.

grep "string1" "sring2" file.txt is not working.

Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Please note that if grep is not used what other option we can use for this purpose. Also the first string is present in 1st line of the file and the string2 is present in some other line of the file.

Comment: So you like to know it both pattern exist in the same file, in any line?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
grep "string1.*string2" file
```

In this test `string1` must come before `string2` in same line to bee true.

---

Or you can do:

```
grep string1 file | grep string2
```

This will be true if `string1` and `string2` is found

---

Using `awk`

```
awk '/string1/ && /string2/' file
```

---

To search on any line

```
awk '/string1/ {f1=1} /string2/ {f2=1} END {if (f2 && f1) print "found"}' file
```

---

To get exit status (cred Adrian)

```
awk '/string1/ {f1=1} /string2/ {f2=1} END {exit !(f1 && f2)}' file
```

This will give exit status `0` of both pattern is found, `1` if not

Comment: `awk` is the way to go here but your example will *not* exit >0 if it doesn't find both strings.

Comment: You got the logic reversed, it will `exit 1` if both patterns are found right now. I think you meant `if (f1 && f2) exit 0; exit 1` or `exit !(f1 && f2)` instead?

Comment: You are correct, updated with your suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "foo bar quux" | awk 'BEGIN{r=1} /foo/&&/bar/{r=0} END{exit r}'
$ echo $?
0

$ echo "foo bar quux" | awk 'BEGIN{r=1} /blah/&&/blubb/{r=0} END{exit r}'
$ echo $?
1
```

For a more dynamic approach check out [Dennis Williamson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4798219/612462).

Answer (score 1):

If you want both patterns to be present in the same or in different line (in the same file) consider this simple thing:

`grep string1 file.txt && grep string2 file.txt`

It will be successful only if both (&&) were successful, it will optimize the Boolean logic and only run second if the first was successful - which does not matter, unless you want to do something more:

You can group it and make an 'then/else' kind of thing - mind the `()` which give you the result of the whole grep && grep: `(grep string1 file.txt && grep string2 file.txt) && echo "This file is OK" || echo "I don't like this file"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following:

```
grep 'word1\|word2\|word3' /path/to/file
```

Or maybe on UNIX:

```
grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 /path/to/file
```