# grep for two words in log file that are not in same line

Tags: grep

```
2019/08/20 18:36:29.710 [1cdc10a5-7d27-4cf2-8890-0f8f0b21798c Dispatcher] [INFO ] com.vmware.nfc.platform.streaming.infraprocessors.processors.MetricsInfraProcessor.handleMessage(MetricsInfraProcessor.java:39) - DEBUG - Parsed:metric_entry {
  reference_oid {
    oid: "2:51323330635433366"
  }
  metric_name: "up_time"
  metric_type: COUNTER
  metric_point {
    timestamp: 1566324769337211363
    value: 73743.0
  }
}
```

I need to search a pattern in my log file which has oid as "2:51323330635433366" and metric_name  as "up_time".

```
root$ grep -A3 2:51323330635433366 patten1.log | grep up_time
  metric_name: "up_time"
```

It give me the a single line as `metric_name: "up_time"`. I want to print the whole block.

How do I do it?

Comment: What have you tried for yourself?

Comment: This might help: [grep for multiple strings in file on different lines (ie. whole file, not line based search)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4795323/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a empty line between every section like example below, you can use `gnu awk` and set Record Selector to nothing.

Eks data

```
2019/08/20 18:36:29.710 [1cdc10a5-7d27-4cf2-8890-0f8f0b21798c Dispatcher] [INFO ] com.vmware.nfc.platform.streaming.infraprocessors.processors.MetricsInfraProcessor.handleMessage(MetricsInfraProcessor.java:39) - DEBUG - Parsed:metric_entry {
  reference_oid {
    oid: "2:51323330635433366"
  }
  metric_name: "up_time"
  metric_type: COUNTER
  metric_point {
    timestamp: 1566324769337211363
    value: 73743.0
  }
}

2019/08/20 18:36:29.710 [1cdc10a5-7d27-4cf2-8890-0f8f0b21798c Dispatcher] [INFO ] com.vmware.nfc.platform.streaming.infraprocessors.processors.MetricsInfraProcessor.handleMessage(MetricsInfraProcessor.java:39) - DEBUG - Parsed:metric_entry {
  reference_oid {
    oid: "2:51323d30635433366"
  }
  metric_name: "up_time"
  metric_type: COUNTER
  metric_point {
    timestamp: 1566324769337211363
    value: 73743.0
  }
}
```

Then `awk` will work with blocks.

```
awk -v RS="" '/2:51323330635433366/ && /up_time/' file
2019/08/20 18:36:29.710 [1cdc10a5-7d27-4cf2-8890-0f8f0b21798c Dispatcher] [INFO ] com.vmware.nfc.platform.streaming.infraprocessors.processors.MetricsInfraProcessor.handleMessage(MetricsInfraProcessor.java:39) - DEBUG - Parsed:metric_entry {
  reference_oid {
    oid: "2:51323330635433366"
  }
  metric_name: "up_time"
  metric_type: COUNTER
  metric_point {
    timestamp: 1566324769337211363
    value: 73743.0
  }
}
```

There are other ways this can be done, depending on how the data is separated.